# Is possible to get HTTP status code in side SOAP Extensions C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, soap-extension

I create C# webservice with soap extension base on this article :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esw638yk(v=vs.71).aspx
 for keep soap log,Is it possible to get http status code in soap extension section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer by add

```
HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
String HTTPCODE = ctx.Response.StatusCode.ToString();
```